# Avoid text near image in responsive design (HTML)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have header with an image, but when I shrink the window, text below the image appears at right side of image. I try `clear: both` and it doesn't work, but after adding div with height 100px it works properly. I use Bootstrap class for responsive layout.Thanks in response.

**Edited:**  [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25106/)

HTML:

```
<header class="row-fluid">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Pastegraph" style="float: left;"> 
     </div>                
     <a href="https://github.com/misteraverin/pastegraph">
         <img class="fork" src="img/forkme.png" alt="forkme">
     </a>
     <!-- <div style="height:100px;"></div> -->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
img.fork {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Screenshot of the text appearing near the image:

[image: text appears near image]

Comment: share your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: have you tried putting them in different <div> with row class in each ?

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman what for?

Comment: Don't use col-md class of bootstrap. This alignment problem that you are facing is due to this class. Instead use row class in header image <div>.

Comment: i am suspecting the image `fork me on github` has  `position:fixed` so that could be your problem try adding the style`padding-right:padding amt in px untill the image stops going near the image (say 150px)`

Comment: @ImmortalDude it doesn't work at all.

Comment: post the link to your page

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ? you want the github image to appear on top of the logo text ? or what

Comment: You want logo and the followings in one line or in next line?

Comment: @SaurabhLP next

Comment: Simply remove `float:left;` from the image...